# Error creating TermDocumentMatrix in tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am new to the `tm` package, and have run into an obstacle when trying to apply the `TermDocumentMatrix` function.

I have used the following code up until the function fails:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(posts$message))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)

removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)

myStopwords <- c(stopwords("english"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus 
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
```

Upon inspection it seems as if the list of documents is what it should be:

```
> for(i in 1:5) {
+   cat(paste("[[", i, "]] ", sep =""))
+   writeLines(myCorpus[[i]])
+ }
[[1]] syntel recruitment drive   week  freshers  newregistrationlink    passout graduates
qualification   graduatebebtechmcamemtech
syntel registration link  
limited referrals available 
comment  emailids  reference  future job upd
[[2]] dont miss  opportunity   get placed  one   best mnc companies   world ebay freshers  week  january 
qualification   graduate can apply
ebay registration link  
comment  emailids fast beacuse    referrals left
[[3]] recent passouts      eligible  apply  wipro  go   updated link  lastday reference drive jan  apply link  fresher referral
apply link 
go   link  apply asap
[[4]] robertbosch recruitment drive   week  freshers  newregistrationlink    passout graduates
qualification   graduatebebtechmcamemtech
robertbosch registration link  
limited referrals available 
comment  emailids  reference  future job upd
[[5]] mega job openings   year
mphasis recruitment  freshers january 
qualification   btech bsc bca  graduates mca mba  mtech post graduates
mphasis registration link  
comment  emailids  comment box  reference  future job updates   emailbox
```

however, after creating a copy of corpus for stem completion, the problem arises.

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion,
                   dictionary = myCorpusCopy, lazy = TRUE)
> tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(x$content[i], function(d) tm_reduce(d, x$lazy$maps)) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to recall

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus))
```

before using the **TermDocumentMatrix**, your final piece of code will be:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary = myCorpusCopy)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
```

If until the stemming of the document no error occured, the previous instructions will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you might try first:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

Before you use

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus))
```